# How to return an object of type string from __repr__?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to use `__repr__` such that it returns an object of type string.

While it seems to return a string, **the type() is not equal to string**:

```
>> ColumnSet.COL_A
Out: "COL_A"
>> type(ColumnSet.COL_A)
Out: __main__.Column
>> type(ColumnSet.COL_A) == str
Out: False
```

However, what I want is:

```
>> ColumnSet.COL_A
Out: "COL_A"
>> type(ColumnSet.COL_A)
Out: str
>> type(ColumnSet.COL_A) == str
Out: True
```

Explicitly casting the return value to string inside `__repr__` does not solve it. I am using `__repr__` in the hopes of still being able to execute queries such as `ColumnSet.COL_A.data_type` etc.

This is my current implementation:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass


@dataclass
class Column:
    column_name: str
    data_type: str
    description: str

    def __repr__(self) -> str:
        return str(self.column_name)


@dataclass
class ColumnSet:
  COL_A = Column(
      **{
          "column_name": "COL_A",
          "data_type": "bool",
          "description": "Lorem Ipsum",
      }
  )
  COL_B = Column(
      **{
          "column_name": "COL_B",
          "data_type": "bool",
          "description": "Lorem Ipsum",
      }
  )
```

Comment: You are looking at the type of the instance of `Column`, not of its `__repr__`. It will be `str` when you do `type(repr(ColumnSet.COL_A))`. Of course,  `type(ColumnSet.COL_A) == Column`.

Comment: The `type(ColumnSet.COL_A)` → `Column` because you have declared it that way. The `type(repr(ColumnSet.COL_A))` → `str` because it calls `__repr__()` and that is the type *it* returns.

Answer (score 0):

`type` does not call `__repr__` on the object you pass as argument. If it would, then it would have become a useless function, always returning `str`.

If you really wanted the type of those objects to be `str`, then you'd call `repr` on them:

```
class ColumnSet:
  COL_A = repr(Column(
      **{
          "column_name": "COL_A",
          "data_type": "bool",
          "description": "Lorem Ipsum",
      }
  ))
  COL_B = repr(Column(
      **{
          "column_name": "COL_B",
          "data_type": "bool",
          "description": "Lorem Ipsum",
      }
  ))
```

But then really the type is `str`, and `str` does not expose the methods you want to have. For that you need it to be of type `Column`.